# Primeng accordion opens on page load, then closes

Tags: html, angular, accordion, primeng

I have three accordions on a page and every time the page loads, the accordion tabs all load open and then close immediately. I would like all the accordion tabs to just load closed. The code I’m using is just the getting started code for accordion component on primeng website.

Comment: Could you explain a bit further your issue? maybe present a code example?

Comment: When I refresh the page for example, the accordion tabs all appear open for a second and then they close. I just copy and pasted the code from the getting started section of this page: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/accordion